# ConcurrentModificationException in multithreaded unit test despite synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm building a cache and want to unit test it using real multithreading approach.

I declare two fileds:

```
private final Object LOCK = new Object();
private final Map<MaterialSpec, Material> materialsCache = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, I have two methods to get Material from cache and to clear Material from cache:

```
private Material getAndCacheMaterial(MaterialSpec materialSpec) throws OperationFailedException {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        if (materialsCache.containsKey(materialSpec)) {
            return materialsCache.get(materialSpec);
        }
    }

    Material material = materialProvider.getMaterial(materialSpec);

    synchronized (LOCK) {
        materialsCache.put(material.getMaterialSpec(), material);
        if (materialSpec.isDefault()) {
            // cache as "default" material in addition to a specific material
            materialsCache.put(materialSpec, material);
        }
    }
    return material;
}

public void clearMaterialFromCache(String materialId) {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        for (MaterialSpec materialSpec : materialsCache.keySet()) {
            if (materialId.equals(materialSpec.getMaterialId())) {
               materialsCache.remove(materialSpec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all accesses to `materialsCache` Map are synchronized (there are no other places where this field is used). However, despite that, I'm getting ConcurrentModificationException in my unit test:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1516)
    at com.a24z.materials.MaterialsManager.clearMaterialFromCache(MaterialsManager.java:129)
```

My unit test is indeed multithreaded (but I don't think its code is relevant here), so, if the implementation wouldn't be thread-safe, it's reasonable to expect this exception. However, given I synchronized all accesses to this Map, I just can't understand how concurrent modification can happen in this case.

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: @tgdavies, ah, silly me. Yes, of course. It has nothing to do with concurrency - I just modify the collection while iterating. Stupid mistake. Please post this as an anwer so I could accept.

Comment: As there's already a good answer it is better to just let this be closed as a duplicate.